# How to stream only a section of the media file from the web source in JAVA

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming, audio-processing

I'm developing an app that play (demonstrates) the audio files streaming from the web. I'd like to reduce those demonstrations to segments of 30 second, which means streaming only a part of the original audio files (MP3). However I *don't* want to cut the audio files and store those segments as different files on the server, instead my intention is to do it from the original file on-the-fly. I've tried something like the code below without success.

```
AudioInputStream stream=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new URL("http://example.com/test.mp3"));
float rate=stream.getFormat().getFrameRate();
clip.open(stream);
clip.setLoopPoints((int)Math.round(rate*0.1264931), (int)Math.round(rate*0.5258144));
clip.setFramePosition((int)Math.round(rate*0.1264931));
clip.loop(1);
```

I'd like to know is that possible in the form of the above logic or not?

And is there any suggestion for this case *without* making physical segmentations?